# how to debug passport

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, passport.js

I can't for the life of me seem to figure out how to debug a passport strategy. Am I just conceptually doing something horribly wrong? I've been banging my head at this for about 10 hours now, and haven't gotten a single bit closer.

This is my first time using passport. In this particular scenario, I'm using passport-jwt. I know that the object keys aren't right, but I'm just trying to trace the path through the server using console.log() so I understand how things work. I'm not even reaching the `passport.use( new JwtStrategy(..))`.

I've left out unnecessary code. The connection to my mongodb is fine and my mongoose schema's are fine.

I'm testing using a test route `server.get('/fakelogin', ...)` that does a request-promise POST to `/api/login`. I've also tried using a `curl -X POST` and modifying the post route to url query parameter. I just constantly get an "Unauthorized" error without the passport strategy code console.log ever firing.

#### Server

```
var server = express();
server.use(passport.initialize());

let opts = {
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromBodyField('token'),
    secretOrKey: config.apiKey,
    algorithms: [ 'HS256', 'HS384' ],
    ignoreExpiration: true
};

passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function( jwt_payload, done ) {
    // mongoose users query against JWT content

    return done(null, true); // EDIT: test to finish flow
}));

server.use('/api', routes);
server.listen(8000);
```

#### Routes

```
let routes = express.Router();

routes.post('/securedroute', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
    ( req, res ) => {
        res.send('success');
    }
);

routes.get('/testsecure', ( req, res ) => { // EDIT: mock request with JWT
    let options = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'http://localhost:8000/api/authentication/securedroute',
        body: {
            token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwiZW1haWwiOiJhQGEuY29tIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.afjyUmC81heavGBk7l9g7gAF5E6_eZeYSeE7FNmksp8'
        },
        json: true
    };

    rp(options)
    .then( ( info ) => res.json({ info }) )
    .catch( ( err ) => res.json({ err }) );
});

export default routes;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made a couple edits to the code above to finish the flow.

Totally understand that this is super n00b, but hopefully it'll help a beginner trying to understand auth.

So completely missed the fact that you need to send a JWT in the request. The JWT used in the request needs to use the same secret as what you defined in your passport-jwt strategy opts.secretOrKey. If they don't match, you will get an unauthorized and never reach the passport.use strategy block.

**Generated a HMAC**
http://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html

**Created a test JWT**
https://jwt.io/#debugger

**Greate guide, i eventually found**
http://jonathanmh.com/express-passport-json-web-token-jwt-authentication-beginners/